I'm training a model of machine learning polynomial regression using pytorch, and im getting errors while trying to plot the results of my predictions
I want to plot my data into a plt.scatter form but when I try to fill it, it just says that the x and y are not of the same size, and I also squeezed them to only one dimension so that it is easier to plot, but still it didn't work.
This is the plot mechanism:
#visualize the data with a scatter (x,y) from matplotlib.pyplot
def plot_predictions(train_features=X_train,
                     train_labels=y_train,
                     test_features=X_test,
                     test_labels=y_test,
                     predictions=None):
    plt.figure(figsize= (10,7))

    plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, c="g", label="training data")

    plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, c="b",  label="testing data")

    if predictions is not None:
        plt.scatter(test_features ,predictions, c="r", label="predictions")

    plt.legend(prop={"size" : 14})

plot_predictions()

#here to check if there is are missmatch shapes
X_train.shape, y_train.shape, y_preds.shape

#output (torch.Size([24, 1]), torch.Size([24, 1]), torch.Size([24, 1]))
#here trying to solve the problem
predictions_reshaped=y_preds.squeeze(dim=1)
labels_reshaped=y_train.squeeze(dim=1)
print(len(y_train), len(y_preds))
print(labels_reshaped.shape, predictions_reshaped.shape)

#the output
#24 24
#torch.Size([24]) torch.Size([24])
#torch.Size([6, 1]) torch.Size([6, 1])


labels_reshaped=y_train.detach().numpy()
predictions_reshaped=y_preds.detach().numpy()
plot_predictions(labels_reshaped, predictions=predictions_reshaped)


ValueError: x and y must be the same size

I tried to squeeze the tensors so that they are only one dim, and also I checked if the len was the same and it was.

The question title should describe your problem, not your circumstances that led to the problem. Think of Stack Overflow like a big FAQ, not like a discussion forum.

Also, note that we need code to be a [mre] -- the shortest thing we can run to see the exact same problem ourselves. That means including the shortest/simplest possible data, f/e, that should be able to be plotted but instead triggers the same error.

What are the values for labels_reshaped.shape, predictions_reshaped.shape, X_test.shape, and y_test.shape? I think the issue is a shape mismatch between the first pair, the last pair, or both.

show an example of the data.
